# Lake Victoria bathymetric data

Tags: geospatial

I am trying to find bathymetry for Lake Victoria (or portions).

Any GIS format and almost any resolution will do.

As a last resort a hydrographic chart will suffice.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116738/lake-victoria-bathymetric-data

Comment: lake victoria....in africa? thats what google says but i'm just not familiar so asking for clarification

Comment: Yes in Africa, Kenya, Tanzania, Uganda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made my own from 10,000 points. http://bit.ly/LV_Bathy is the URL.

[image]

Comment: Very cool data product. One suggestion: it would be good to point to an xml document with the reference system and other metadata (EPSG 102024, right?).

Comment: Will do in pdf.

Comment: It is in the official metadata at the Harvard Dataverse.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a GIS Portal to Lake Victoria at William & Mary University in Williamsburg, VA

http://www.wm.edu/as/programs/lake_victoria/GIS_DATA/index.php

This site says it has Shapefiles with bathymetry for Lake Victoria

https://figshare.com/articles/Lake_Victoria_Shapefiles/1494839

Comment: lol. w&m is a uni but they certainly maintain the college of william & mary name. i know a few tribe alums that would cringe at that wording. not like you did anything wrong...just throwing some commentary in here

Comment: @albert - thanks for the note. Ya, even the W&M website seems to intersperse using University and College.